# Nginx try_files with regex

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to configure my Nginx conf file but it doesnt want to work ...

I want to serve some pdf files.

When you write the url "127.0.0.1/abcFile.pdf" Nginx should serve you the file which is located here : "/a/b/c/abcFile.pdf"

I can have multiple folders. Each time first 3 letters of the file name are the folders names.

So i'm trying this :

```
location ~* "\.(\w{1})(\w{1})(\w{1})(\w*.pdf)$" {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4 ;
}
```

But I only got an error 500... I can't figure out what i'm missing here.

This kind of code work with rewrite:

```
rewrite "(\w{1})(\w{1})(\w{1})(\w*.pdf)" $1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4 permanent;
```

But here i'v an issue too : Too many redirect. If I remove the "permanent" it doesn't work anymore.

If you have any suggestion :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: The first regex starts with a `.`. Shouldn't that be a `/` or even a `^/`? In the `rewrite` statement, the rewritten URI needs a leading `/`.

Comment: @Richard You just saved me on this issue. My mistake was the `.` instread of a `^/`. I'v just spend many hours on that ... Thanks a lot !! :)